# Weird combobox for technology option on salary calculator on Chrome for Android

Tags: bug, mobile-web, google-chrome, salary-calculator

Technology option combobox for [salary calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary) opened on mobile version on Android Chrome contains weird checkbox on the top level:

> [image]

Comment: Does it select all?

Comment: @Will nope. Neither select, nor unselect.